# You can only do so many of them

Tags: idioms, vocabulary

I heard this one in a documentary about foot fetish.

The woman who produces fetish videos says:

> A lot men like feet. But you can only do so many of them.

What does this mean? I googled but couldn't find any idiom like this. I found however similar usages, like:

> "You can only do so many bar crawls. Get some culture into your
>   life,..." "You can only do so many tasks at one time, so it makes
>   sense to focus in on what is really required." "You can only do so
>   many movies in a certain time, so I've acted outside of those ones
>   too. So, it wasn't really that big of a thing."

Thank you.

Comment: She's either talking about the men or the videos. It's not clear from the information you've provided.

Comment: You can only do a certain number of "feet" videos, despite it being a common fetish among men. That is to say, the theme is a fairly limited one, you can only do so many (videos) before it becomes repetitive, predictable, boring etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*so many X* often means "a limited number of X".

> A lot men like feet. But you can only do so many of them.

means that you cannot probably do all men that like feet. There's a limit.

Here *do* means *have sex with*.

**Update:** Considering the comments, however, it now seems far more plausible to me that she's talking about foot fetish movies, rather than men. So she is saying that although a lot of men like feet, you can only make a limited number of foot fetish movies.

Comment: While that's one possible interpretation, another is that *do* refers to making videos-  *But you can only make so many videos.* This actually feels to me like the more likely interpretation because she's not a prostitute, she's a movie producer.

Answer (score 0):

It's a joke.  You can only do two per person.  If it were a toe fetish, perhaps you could do up to ten per person.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of men like pancakes, but you can only feed them so many pancakes before they get tired of eating pancakes every day. Even if you spice it up by putting whipped cream or fruit on the pancakes, eventually the men will still grow to like pancakes less and less as they indulge in them repeatedly.

Replace pancakes with foot fetish videos... or just about anything else for that matter.